# Measuring the difference in two sets of numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have multiple sets of numbers considered prediction and then a final set called the result. I would like to have a measurement of the difference between each prediction and the result. Obviously, there are easy ways to do this for each value, but I'm looking for an approach that serves as a summary of the difference between the sets.

Comment: Sum of squared differences?  Works quite well in many contexts.

Comment: If your two sets are of the same length, then the Hamming distance sounds like it might be useful.